# How to make .one () method to work again without reloading the page

Tags: javascript

I have a chat application and I made that when the user writes in the TEXTAREA field to add a text under his name for example Typing ... but for personal reasons I would like this "Typing ..." to appear only once without repeating for each character.
I tried with the one () function but it works again only if user reloads the page.

```
$("textarea").one('input', function () {
    HERE IS MY CODE TO ADD "TYPING.." UNDER HIS NAME
});
```

```
function sendMessage() {

HERE IS MY CODE TO DELETE "TYPING..." FROM UNDER HIS NAME

}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You want the message to only appear once. So why do you say "it works *again* only if...". "once" and "again" .... Let me think... Do you want it once or again?

Comment: Add the text in a `<span>` with a specific class/id. Check before adding if the element is already there. Remove the element when submitting the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a kind of [throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throttling_process_(computing)), using the following `setTimeout`-based, function:

```js
// Returns a function that will call its callback argument 
// only when a certain delay has passed. Another callback
// can be called to notify that the delay has expired
function throttle(f, milliseconds, ready = () => null) {
    let timer = -1;
    
    return function () {
        if (timer === -1) f();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            timer = -1;
            ready();
        }, milliseconds);
    }
}

function sendMessage(msg) {
    $("div").text("typing...");
}

function clearMessage() {
    $("div").text("");
}

$("textarea").on('input', throttle(sendMessage, 3000, clearMessage));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div></div>
```

The "typing..." message will clear when during 3 seconds there was no typing. If typing starts again, then the message will be sent/displayed again. The message will not be sent again before it has been cleared.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your are the best!

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a timeout, that will revert the typing state after a certain time. Clear the timeout while the user keeps typing.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('.area')
const indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator')
let timeout = null

textArea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout)

  indicator.innerText = 'Typing...'

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    indicator.innerText = ''
  }, 300)
})
```

```css
.area,
.indicator {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="area"></textarea>
<span class="indicator"></span>
```